# How to call python OpenCV on the browser in a WSGI application

Tags: python, django, opencv, redis, wsgi

I am building a face detection web app. I have a WSGI client & server. The client is supposed to capture the frames and pass it to Redis datastore. The server is supposed to process the images and send it back. The problem I am facing is that the WSGI client is calling the python OpenCV library on the browser which isn't being loaded. Is there anyway I can use the python OpenCV library on the browser using Django maybe? I'm quite new to Django/WSGI so any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Use another framework for this, kinda like Flask or FastAPI.

Comment: have you tried using StreamingHttpResponse?

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d84/tutorial_js_usage.html